# no response when form is sent

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to crewate a form fro listing databases on mysql, select one from the radio list and create a table with required parameters but it acts like it isn't even submitting. I see the url change but my code isn't running at all.
This is the form data:

```
SELECT DATABASE TO WORK WITH
<form action = "createtable.php" action = "post">
<?php 
$query = "SHOW DATABASES";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(!$result){echo mysql_error(); var_dump($result);
var_dump($connect); var_dump($query);}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{echo '<input type = "radio" name = "db"/>' . $row[0] . "<br>";}
?>
<input type = "text" name = "text" />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />

</form>
```

and the code to execute is:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo 'submit done';
$db = $_POST['db'];
$query = "USE $db";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(!$result){echo 'no' . mysql_error();}

echo 'working';

$table = 'rio';
$id = 'id';
$idtype = 'int';
$idno = '11';
$staffmenu = 'staffmenu';
$stafftype = 'varchar';
$staffno = '255';
$null = 'NOT NULL';
$ai = 'auto_increment';
$key = 'id';

$query ="CREATE TABLE staff 
($id $idtype($idno) $null $ai,
$staffmenu $stafftype($staffno) $null,
subj varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ($key))";
var_dump($query);
$result2 = mysql_query($query, $connect);
if(!$result2){echo mysql_error();}

//session_destroy();

} 

?>
```

i tried to use a different variable to trigger the code asides submit but that didn't work either. Any help will be appreciated. I am also aware of the deprecation of mysql, but i'm not totally sure how to migrate to mysqli so please bear with me.

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions they are deprecated, but I will still look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To post your form you need `method = "post"` instead of `action = "post"`

```
<form action = "createtable.php" method = "post">
```

instead of

```
 <form action = "createtable.php" action = "post">
```

Also, You need to add the value in your radio input as well,

```
 echo '<input type = "radio" name = "db" value="'.$row[0].'"  />' . $row[0] . "<br>";
```

Comment: i actually did not see that mistake. I'm soory for that

Answer (score 0):

Change your **form's method** type to **post**

you haven't mentioned your form's submission type